# Searchbutton not aligned with searchfield

Tags: html, css, internet-explorer

I am trying to style a search form but the search button seems to be positioned a little bit lower in internet explorer than firefox and any other browser I have tested so far.
I would like to have the search button perfectly aligned with the searchfield. If possible a fix for most internet explorers.

Here's a picture showing the problem and a [JSfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/KmG5G/).

[image: picture]

Though it seems that the JsFiddle shows the search button aligned to the searchform in internet explorer.

Thanks in advance for any help.
~dragon54

~~~~

I solved my problem.

I use conditional comments to let Internet Explorer use different css files. (Those were not in the JSfiddle). I took a look at it and removed unnecessary code which linked to a wrong css file. This solved the problem.

Thanks for all the answers they were all very helpful!

Comment: If it shows up correctly in JSFiddle, then you've caused the problem yourself through your CSS. You did reset the browser default CSS, didn't you?

Answer (score 0):

Just put both text fields and button in a div and set style for that div.